# myget edit build to automatically build with checkin

Tags: myget

I have a MyGet build defined for which I initially turned off the automatic build with check-in.  I'd like to now enable that feature.

Can I do this without having to recreate the build?  I don't see it in the build editor dialog.

Comment: You can always register a build hook with GitHub to do this (under your repo settings' service hooks)

Comment: I forgot I asked this question. Got help from MyGet support. @maartenba, if you want to leave a detailed description on how to do that, you can have some points.